# python glob2/formic style recursive wildcard pattern search for lists

Tags: python, glob

I need a [GLOB2](https://github.com/miracle2k/python-glob2) or [FORMIC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/formic) like solution to search a large list of directories in a text file (the files aren't on my machine, the file list is produced by an external process i cannot directly access or query)

pseudo example:

```
# read the large directory list in memory
data = []
with open('C:\\log_file.txt','r') as log:
    data = log.readlines()

# query away!
query1 = listglob(data,'/**/fnord/*/log.*')
query2 = listglob(data,'/usr/*/model_*/fnord/**')
```

Unless someone has a suggestion, my next step is to open up glob2 and formic and see if one of them can be changed to accept a list instead of a root folder to be "os.walked"

Comment: Take a look at the [`fnmatch` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html); it doesn't support `**` arbitrary-depth directory matching, but does let you match strings against glob patterns.

Comment: I see that `glob2` includes its own version of that module, but implements the `**` support for real files only (on top of `os.walk()`), similar to how the patch for [this Python ticket](http://bugs.python.org/issue13968) works.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using regular expressions. Ultimately, both Formic and `glob` use an OS call to perform the actual glob matching. So, if you want to modify either, you're going to have to write a RE matcher (or similar) in any case. So, cut out the middle-man and go straight to REs. (It pains me to say that because I'm the author of Formic).

The basic plan is to write a function that takes in your glob and returns a regular expression. Here are some pointers:

1. Escape and `.`, `-` and other RE reserved characters in your globs. Eg `.` becomes `\.`
2. A `?` in a glob file/directory becomes `[^/]` (matches a single character that's not a `/`)
3. A `*` in a glob file/directory name as a regular expression is `[^/]*`
4. A `/*/` glob as a regular expression is: `/[^/]+/`
5. A `/**/` glob as a regular expression is: `/([^/]+/)*`
6. To match a whole line, start the RE with a `^` and end it with `$`. This forces the RE to expand over the whole string.

While I listed the substitutions in order of increasing complexity, it's probably a good idea to do the substitutions in the following order:

1. Special RE characters that are not globs (`.`, `-`, '$', etc)
2. `?`
3. `/**/`
4. `/*/`
5. `*`

This way you won't corrupt the `/**/` when substituting for a single `*`.

In your question you have: `/**/fnord/*/log.*`. This would map to:

```
^/([^/]+/)*fnord/[^/]+/log\.[^/]*
```

Once you've built your RE, then finding matches is a simple exercise.

Comment: Great answer! In the end i made myself a procedure using glob2. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

In the end i used one of glob2's functions, like so:

```
import glob2

def listglob(data,pattern):
    return [x for x in items if glob2.fnmatch.fnmatch(x,pattern)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the `glob2.fnmatch.fnmatch` is equivalent to the `glob2 **` syntax.

It is equivalent to the `fnmatch` syntax from what i can tell from reading the source code.

Also Andrew's answer doesn't cover the square brackets. and the `[!abc]` example